# Subscribing to Multiple Nodes Publishing the Same Topic

Tags: ros, nodes, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am having an issue that I'm not sure has been addressed. I am writing a node where I am attempting to subscribe to another two nodes that publish to the same topic (i.e. two lasers that are publishing to a topic with the same name). Going back and changing the topic names would be a little bit tricky, so I was wondering if there was a way to differentiate these two (i.e. write a subscriber that takes into account topic name and node-of-origin name when being instantiated.

Thanks

Edit:
I'm confused how the syntax works for remapping and was wondering if I could ask for more help:

Originally, I have as a launch file:

```
<launch>

    <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_front" args="scan:=scan_front $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen"/>

    <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_rear" args="scan:=scan_rear $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen"/>

</launch>
```

I tried this:

```
 <launch>

    <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_front" args="scan:=scan_front $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen"/>

    <group>
      <remap from="leg_tracker_measurements" to="leg_tracker_measurements_rear">
      <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_rear" args="scan:=scan_rear $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen"/>
    </group>
  </launch>
```

But it threw an invalid syntax error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187328/subscribing-to-multiple-nodes-publishing-the-same-topic/) by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-23**:
'Close' your remap tag.

or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know of a way to distinguish by which node sent a message in the callback on the subscriber side.

I suggest you make your two publishing nodes publish to two different topics and your subscriber then subscribe to both indivially. [Remapping topics](http://answers.ros.org/question/9248/how-do-you-remap-a-topic/) is your friend here.

**Edit:**

In response to your syntax problem: Have you read the actual error message? It probably indicates that you forgot to close the `<remap>` tag. You can put it into a group, but I believe it is clearer to put it directly inside the node tag. Also inside a rules file I would not use the remapping syntax with command line arguments like you do for `scan`. This is just confusing. Try this:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_front" args="$(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="scan_front" />
    <remap from="leg_tracker_measurements" to="leg_tracker_measurements_front" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_rear" args="$(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="scan_rear" />
    <remap from="leg_tracker_measurements" to="leg_tracker_measurements_rear" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Or alternatively and maybe even better in this case with namespaces, like suggested in another answer below:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_front" args="$(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen" ns="front" />
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector_rear" args="$(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen" ns="rear" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-21**:
That looks like an awesome feature, thanks so much for the quick reply. So, the way I have it set up I instantiate two instances of the node in the launch file with different names. It seems like I should be able to use the remapping, but does that sound right. Thanks again.

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-21**:
I don't have time to check it out yet, but this seems to work, and I'll make it the answer once I figure out if it does. Thanks

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-21**:
Sounds right. Use the  tag in your launch file for one (or if you like both) of the nodes. Feel free to update your question with more concrete info if you get stuck.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-22**:
Although @McMurdo's answer is the precise reply to the question asked, it is important to note that this answer is the right way to do it!

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-23**:
Alright that worked out well, thanks so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for completeness: You could also launch your two nodes in different name spaces.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-22**:
So I had already renamed both nodes from which the topics were being published from, if that what you man by name spaces. But I believe I still run into the same issue that the nodes both publish to the same topic.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
No, the name of the nodes is not what is referred to here. The node tag can have a `ns` attribute (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node). This causes all topics for this node to have prefix. E.g. if your node publishes to the `data` topic. If you add `ns="foo"` it will then publish to `foo/data`.

**Comment by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) on 2014-07-22**:
Would you mind looking at the code provided in the edit to the main question? I'm not sure where I'm going wrong there

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The real answer is there in the connection header:

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers see the last few lines.

```
A subscriber can get access to a "connection header", which includes debugging information such as who sent the message, as well information like whether or not a message was latched. This data is stored as the _connection_header field of a received message.

e.g.

print m._connection_header
{'callerid': '/talker_38321_1284999593611',
 'latching': '0',
 'md5sum': '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1',
 'message_definition': 'string data\n\n',
 'topic': '/chatter',
 'type': 'std_msgs/String'}
```

EDIT: THIS METHOD IS NOT RECOMMENDED. IT IS ONLY FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Well, I would not rely on that tbh. The section you link says directly after your quote: "We do not recommend using callerid information beyond debugging purposes, as it can lead to brittle code in an anonymous publish/subscribe architecture." And I don't think this is available with C++?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-22**:
Yes. The answer is merely precise, not recommended. see @dornhege's comment below.I should edit the answer to point out that it isn't recommended.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-22**:
In C++ there is a callback signature that subscribes to MessageEvents that hold the publisher's name, see: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Ah, I wasn't aware of the MessageEvent form for callbacks in roscpp. Thanks for pointing that out.